# Quickfix support for fpml

Tags: java, c++, quickfix, fix-protocol, fpml

I am trying to figure out if quickfix supports fpml. I am guessing not , since i could not tell by googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Neither [QuickFIX](http://www.quickfixengine.org/) nor [QuickFIX/J](http://www.quickfixj.org/) support protocols other than [FIX](http://fixprotocol.org/) (4.0 - 4.4, 5.0).

Answer (score 2):

You may encounter some cases where the FIX provider will embed a fpml message inside the FIX message. The tags EncodedSecurityDescLen (350) and EncodedSecurityDesc (351) will be used to store this payload.

QuickFIX/J can manage this kind of message, but you will have to handle the content of the EncodedSecurityDesc yourself. More details in this [page](http://fixprotocol.org/documents/1349/FIXFpML%20Proposal.doc)

Answer (score 0):

Quickfix doesn't supports anything which is not in the FIX standard. FpML is for OTC derivatives, as is mentioned on their website. But you can use a sort of a hack to encompass some of the details which are available in FpML(XML schema).

Quickfix depends on the XML file to check for data in the FIX messages and FIX allows for customized user fields. You can use the data from the FpML standards and use them in your customized user fields in the FIX specification files which your Quickfix engine uses. Not a beautiful method, but works.

Answer (score 0):

You find now initial information about the [Fix Working Group at fpml.org](http://www.fpml.org/wgroup/fixwg/fixwg.html). The FpML-FIX Working Group works to support interoperability between the FIX, FIXML and FpML protocols.